# Forward email message to remote smtp server in Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want to create a SMTP-Gateway that filters emails and redirects them to the remote SMTP server.

```
from smtpd import SMTPServer
from email.parser import Parser

class SMTPGateway(SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, **kwargs):
        print('Processing message...')

        email = Parser().parsestr(data)
        for part in email.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                text = part.get_payload()
                # Process text

        # forward email to upstream smtp server
```

With this code I can receive a message and process it. But I don't know how to forward the message to the remote server.

In my main program, I create the server like this:

```
localaddress = ('localhost', 3000)
remoteaddress = ('localhost', 9000)

gateway = SMTPGateway(localaddress, remoteaddress)
```

**How can I redirect the message in `process_message` to the remote server?**

The documentation of the SMTP-Server is very short:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html.
I could not find the answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

```
from smtpd import SMTPServer
from email.parser import Parser

class SMTPGateway(SMTPServer):
def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, **kwargs):
    print('Processing message...')

    email = Parser().parsestr(data)
    for part in email.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
            text = part.get_payload()
            # Process text

    # forward email to upstream smtp server
    ip = self._remoteaddr[0]
    port = self._remoteaddr[1]
    server = SMTP(ip, port)
    server.send_message(email)
    server.quit()
```