# Python how to forward messages from server

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello i have a old discord server which we don't using now. and we created a new server and moved all members there but still some members r there in old server. So is there a option to forward all messages from server A to server B to specific channel.

Update:
I mean like when ever server A gets a message it should be sended to server B to a specific channel. bot is in both server so with that i can forward all incoming message exactly.

Bot Code

```
token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
prefix = "!"

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('\nLogged in as')
    print("Bot Name: " + bot.user.name)
    print("Bot User ID: " + bot.user.id)

old_server = bot.get_server('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
new_channel = bot.get_channel('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()

    if message.server == old_server:
        await bot.send_message(new_channel, message.content)

    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: You can check here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412755/forward-email-message-to-remote-smtp-server-in-python)

Comment: In that link i can't see anything like from were d message is sending to which server? and is that message or email ?

Comment: What do you mean by "all messages"?  New messages, all old messages, last 100 messages from each channel, etc

Comment: @Demotry can you please update your question ? 
What are those messages?
In what format?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  I mean like when ever server A gets a message it should be sended to server B  to a spacific channel.  bot is in both server so with that i can forward all incoming message exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `on_message` event to check when messages are sent to the old server and have the bot post the message to the new server.

Below is example code where the bot will check when the old server gets a message, then posts the same message to a specified channel on the new server.

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    old_server = client.get_server('old_server_id')
    new_channel = client.get_channel('new_channel_id')

    if message.server == old_server:
        await client.send_message(new_channel, message.content + ' - ' + message.author.nick)

client.run('token')
```

Comment: yes added old server id  and new server channel id.

Comment: Is it ok if i add this both line `old_server = client.get_server('old_server_id')
new_channel = client.get_channel('new_channel_id')`  in top or i need to add this near to on_message ?

Comment: Should be fine if it's near the top, after `client` is defined. If you run the example code as is (with replacing necessary information), does it post messages successfully?

Comment: I updated my full code in above question but still bot not posts message in new server.

Comment: Seems that using `client.get_server` and `client.get_channel` outside of events or commands makes them return `None`. Moving the code inside the `on_message` event works. Updated answer.

Comment: yes it worked but it wont show who's message is that just keeps showing messages.

Comment: The bot cannot post on behalf of anyone else, only as itself. The best you can do it customize the message to show who posted it originally.

Comment: I've updated my code to include " - <username>" at after the message. You can do other fancy things but this is the most basic